# ajax input dependiente de combo en diferentes filas

Tags: jquery, ajax, combobox, entrada

tengo el siguiente caso para resolver:

En un tabla, donde agrego filas independientes mediante el botón "Agregar", tengo un combobox que trae datos de la BBDD y necesito que el input *servicio_preciounitario* se complete automáticamente dependiendo de la opción seleccionada en el combo de la misma fila.

¿Alguna sugerencia? Muchas gracias!

Aquí el código.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#add").click(function(){
cant = $('#contador-filas').val();
cant++;
// Obtenemos el numero de columnas (td) que tiene la primera fila
// (tr) del id "tabla"
var tds=$("#servicio tr:first td").length;
// Obtenemos el total de filas (tr) del id "tabla"
var trs=$("#servicio tr").length;
var nuevaFila="<tr id='"+(cant)+"'>";


$('#contador-filas').val(cant)
nuevaFila+="<td><input class='form-control' name='servicio_cantidad["+(cant)+"]' placeholder='Cantidad"+(cant)+"' size='5' type='text' required /> </td>"+
"<td><?php include ("includes/conexion.php"); $resultServicios = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listasyservicios WHERE id_listadeprecios = '$ListaDePreciosSucursal' ORDER BY id_listasyservicios ASC"); ?><select id='servicio_desc["+(cant)+"]' name='servicio_desc["+(cant)+"]' class='form-control custom-select'><option value=''>-Seleccione Servicio-</option><?php while($rowServicio= mysql_fetch_object($resultServicios)){echo "<option value=".$rowServicio->id_listasyservicios.">";echo "".$rowServicio->id_servicio." - ".$rowServicio->nombreservicio."</option>";} ?></select></td>"+

"<td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='servicio_preciounitario["+(cant)+"]' name='servicio_preciounitario["+(cant)+"]' placeholder='0,00' size='10' required /> </td>"+

"<td><input class='form-control' type='text' name='servicio_preciototal["+(cant)+"]' placeholder='0,00' size='10' required /> </td>"+

"<td><div id='del' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger'>Eliminar</div></td>";

nuevaFila+="</tr>";

$("#servicio").append(nuevaFila);

$('#servicio_desc['+(cant)+']').on('change', function() {
  var preciounitario; 
  var servicio = $(this).val(); 


  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "actioncomboServiciosEnRemitos.php",
    dataType: "html",
    data: servicio,
    async : false, 
    success: function(respuesta) {
      preciounitario =  respuesta;
    },
  });


  $('#servicio_preciounitario['+(cant)+']').val('');

  $('#servicio_preciounitario['+(cant)+']').val(preciounitario);
});



});

});
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#del', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<table id="servicio">
      <thead id="borrarAncla">
        <tr>
    <th>Cantidad</th>
    <th>Servicio</th>
    <th>Precio Unitario</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th><div id="add" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Agregar</div></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>


      </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías dar un id a la tabla, aquí le ha llamado `myTable`, y escuchar los cambios de cualquier `select` dentro de es tabla, luego buscar el `input` que está antes del `select` y cambiar el valor.

Si sólo te interesa escuchar la fila 1, entonces cambias `#myTable` por el id de esa fila y escuchará sólo el `select`de esa fila.

Prueba este ejemplo.

```js
$('#myTable select').on('change', function() {
  var newValue=$(this).val();
  var $previousInput = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first input:text');
  $previousInput.val(newValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr id="tr1">
    <td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='servicio_preciounitario[1]' name='servicio_preciounitario[1]' placeholder='0,00' size='10' required /> </td>
    <td>
      <select id='servicio_desc[1]' name='servicio_desc[1]' class='form-control custom-select'>
        <option value=''>-Seleccione Servicio-</option>
        <option value='100.99'>Servicio 1</option>
        <option value='500.00'>Servicio 2</option>
       </select></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="tr2">
    <td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='servicio_preciounitario[2]' name='servicio_preciounitario[1]' placeholder='0,00' size='10' required /> </td>
    <td>
      <select id='servicio_desc[2]' name='servicio_desc[2]' class='form-control custom-select'>
        <option value=''>-Seleccione Servicio-</option>
        <option value='1000.00'>Servicio 2.1</option>
        <option value='8000.00'>Servicio 2.2</option>
       </select></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Esa fue la solución!

Comment: @pointup Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible lee: ◔_◔ **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** en el Centro de Ayuda.

Comment: Hola @a-cedano ! Necesito hacer una consulta que tiene relación con esta misma pregunta. Lo correcto sería editar la pregunta o crear una nueva?

Comment: @pointup según las normas del sitio lo correcto sería hacer otra pregunta. Ten en cuenta que lo planteado/resuelto aquí podría servir a otros usuarios con el mismo problema y lo mismo la nueva pregunta. Además por lo general obtienes respuesta más rápido al formular una nueva pregunta que al editarla. Las ediciones que cambian el planteamiento original o que tratan de buscar solución a problemas surgidos a posteriori, no son recomendadas en la misma pregunta. Saludos.